# How can I get a history of DNS registration information?

Tags: dns, research

Is there a canonical place that stores DNS registration information? For example for a domain that has changed hands a few times, can I see a listing of the owner information* over time and when the transfers took place?

**whether it's proxied or not*

**Note:** I'm interested in any domain, whether it's an [international TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) or a country coded site.

Comment: Netcraft has (something) like this , but I'm not so sure that it works on all domains, especially domains that contain multibyte characters. Good question :)

Comment: Can we ask what do you need this for?

Comment: Sometimes I want to see the history of a domain, whether it's changed hands, how much the hosting has changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://whois.sc is the closest thing to your requirements that I'm aware of, although they want you to pay if you want access to historical information.

Comment: Do they adequately handle non-ascii domains?

Comment: Quote: "Upgrade your membership to view the historical whois records!"

Comment: Yeah, that's the only site I know of that does anything like this. It's a habit for me to do lookups like http://whois.sc/example.com which redirects to http://whois.domaintools.com/example.com ... I can't even remember how I learned about the site, but it's the only one I know of. Love the question about non-ascii domains. What would be an example of one? Try it out with the pattern `http://whois.sc/*DOMAIN*` and see if it works!

Comment: @Tim - non-ascii domains always have an ASCII equivalent - see http://serverfault.com/questions/142793/can-i-use-the-character-n-in-a-sub-domain

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried http://dnshistory.org? I've tested it with my private - not listed on google - domain and the site returns complete history of NS, MX, A, etc. changes. I don't know how many domains/nameservers the site has "crawled". But i was surprised that the site has found my private domain.

Maybe that fits your needs?

Comment: Seems not to have ownership information, but it does have the records you indicated. Also interesting for showing subdomains for domains. Though I checked a few of my sites and it was ignorant of several public subdomains I have. Spotty, but potentially useful down the line. Thanks!

Comment: Look in the SOA record for the RName:

eg: hostmaster.genotec.ch -> hostmaster@genotec.ch

Answer (score 0):

While it may be possible to get that information for some domains it certainly won't be possible for any and all registrations. Depending on the domain, that information may not be available due to local privacy laws. Also, domains may also be registered through a proxy agent, so the real ownership may never even have been listed.

Comment: I just want to see a history of the public DNS record, The question is not about wanting to get "unmasked" ownership information.